# Gazebo won't launch without restarting PC

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following the tutorials of GazeboSim.
I can spawn the 'RRBot' with *roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch* command, but if I close Gazebo, I cannot
spawn the RRBot again, instead, encounter with this output;

*URDF in parameter [/robot_description] on the ROS param server.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 5212, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver /home/oguzhan/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_demos/rrbot_gazebo/worlds/rrbot.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/oguzhan/.ros/log/4c41b0c0-a00c-11e4-837b-40f02ffcf6f4/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/oguzhan/.ros/log/4c41b0c0-a00c-11e4-837b-40f02ffcf6f4/gazebo-2*.log
[urdf_spawner-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/oguzhan/.ros/log/4c41b0c0-a00c-11e4-837b-40f02ffcf6f4/urdf_spawner-4*.log
*

If I restart my PC, I can spawn the RRBot again with the same command ' *roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch* '.
Again, if I shut it down, I cannot spawn again, but

I tried to kill the process, *killall gzserver* and *pkill gzserver* but it didn't help.
I checked the System Monitor to see if any remaining process running, but it didn't also help.

But after these, I can launch *gazebo* standalone with no problem and also, I can launch gazebo with *roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch*  and I can spawn the Baxter robot with *rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find baxter_description`/urdf/baxter.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model baxter*

But I still fail to spawn the RRBOT with *roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch*

Do you have any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201290/gazebo-won%27t-launch-without-restarting-pc/) by [Oguz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21418/oguz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved:
In rrbot_world.launch file, I commented out:

```
<!--<arg name="world_name" value="$(find rrbot_gazebo)/worlds/rrbot.world"/> -->
```

and it is now working without any problem.

---

Originally posted by [Oguz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21418/oguz/) with karma: 121 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0